# Segmentation Fault (core dumped) Character Arrays

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am attempting to read in a sentence from the user and make it into an array, where each letter holds a character value.  Each time I run the program, I am able to type in the sentence, but after that "Segmentation Fault (core dumped)" appears.  All of this is happening within a function that is called from the main.

```
int words(char sentence[]){
int i=0;
    printf("Please enter your favorite sentence(max 100 characters).\n");
    scanf("%c", &sentence);
            while(sentence != "." && sentence != "!"){
            i++;
            scanf("%c", &sentence[i]);
            }
    printf("%d", i);
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Have you run this through GDB? Also - what if the sentence doesn't end in a period or exclamation point?

Comment: Run it through a debugger like GDB, or use a tool like valgrind. That can very quickly tell what's wrong with the code.

Comment: Perhaps you want your first assignment in `scanf` to be `&sentence[0]` instead?

Comment: In addition to @Evert's suggestion, Shouldn't your while statement be: while(sentence[i] != "." && sentence[i] != "!"){ ?

Comment: @bruceg No, it shouldn't. Don't compare integers with pointers in general case.

Comment: @MikeCAT He's reading a char at a time.  I meant to switch the double quotes to single ones in my prev comment

Answer (score 1):

What does your compiler say when you compile with `-Wall -Wextra`.  You can't expect to write C code correctly without compiling with warnings on.  Everyone says how badly you can mess up with C code, it lets you do anything.  That's true but the warnings are there to help you.

I'm not sure why people are asking you to go to `gdb` or `valgrind`.  For me, this code should never be executed and expect to be right.  My compiler spits out these warnings:

```
words.c: In function ‘words’:
words.c:6: warning: format ‘%c’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’
words.c:7: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior
words.c:7: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior
```

Fix those warnings and then come back if you are still having problems.  Or if you don't understand what those warnings mean then ask a specific question about it.

Comment: Whenever I see "segfault" I immediately send people to GDB.  TBH, it's partially just me being lazy...I'll start defaulting to "compile with `-Wall -Wextra`, fix those errors, then run GDB".  Good point overall.

Comment: @tonysdg: of course *you* default to going to `gdb` because your segfaults are caused by something that warnings didn't catch because you already know to compile with them on!

Comment: Haha that's my point - I should start defaulting my response on SO to be that :) (And no - I forget to compile with those flags more than I care to admit)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this and it will work:

```
char sentence[30];
int i=0;
printf("Enter phrase: \n");
scanf("%c", sentence);
while(sentence[i]!='.' && sentence[i]!='!')
{
        i++;
        scanf("%c",&sentence[i]);
}
printf("%d\n", i);
return i;
```

You just had to remove the '&' from the scanf in the fourth line since sentence alone without the array index indication is a memory adress itself. Note that this works if the sentences always end with a '.' or a '!'. Although i believe there is a better way to do this than reading the sentence one char at a time.